# RemoveChild() error in javascript

Tags: javascript, removechild, dom

I'm using a function in a php file to create some "li" and some "span" elements like so:

```
while($row_quotes=mysql_fetch_array($result_quotes) and $x<10){
$x++;
echo "<li class='citazione'>".$row_quotes['citazione']."</li><span class='citazione_info'>".$row_quotes['personaggio']." - ".$row_quotes['libro']."</span>";
}
```

These are contained inside "ul id='quotes_holder'".
Then I have a javascript function that on a certain call should remove all the created "li" and "span" elements so I thought it would have worked to removing them with the removeChild() method applied on the containing "ul".

Here's the javascript function:

```
function ritorna_filtri(obj, autore){
var index=obj.selectedIndex;
var selected=obj.childNodes[index];
var value= selected.value;
var div=document.getElementById('quotes_holder');
for(l=0;l<div.childNodes.length;l++){
    div.removeChild(div.childNodes[l]);
}

var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        response=xmlhttp.responseText;
        jsonObj=eval("("+response+")");
        for(i=0;i<jsonObj.libri.length;i++){
            var li=document.createElement('li');
            var text=document.createTextNode(jsonObj.libri[i].titolo);
            li.appendChild(text);
            li.setAttribute('class', 'filtro');
            div.appendChild(li);
        }
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","ritorna_filtri.php?filtro="+value+"&autore="+autore,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Problem is when the function is executed only the "li" elements are removed, the "span"s are still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original code does not work since you are looping from `0` to `childNodes.length - 1` but you are forgetting that once you remove item #0 and increment the counter, item #1 is removed in the next iteration; there will still be an item at #0.

The following code can be used to remove an element's content:

```
var div = document.getElementById('quotes_holder');
while (div.firstChild) {
    div.removeChild(div.firstChild);
}​
```

## [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/ztQnT/)

PS: Your HTML markup is invalid.

Answer (score 2):

A note: the only valid child elements for a `ul` are zero or more `li` elements: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/ul

Check out this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MrpeF/

In it, I have created two `ul`s -- one with valid elements (`li` only), the other as you describe, with `span`s as children too. If you observe console as it runs, you'll see that only the `li` elements are contained in `childNodes` (and, oddly, the TextNodes from my code spacing!?). The difference is, the valid HTML has the `span` inside the `li`, so removing the `li` would accomplish your goal.

Another thing worth mentioning is that your `for...` loop is inefficient. By calculating the length of `childNodes` every iteration, you're making the loop cost more than it needs to. Counting the length of the loop before actually entering the loop is more efficient:

```
var looplen = div.childNodes.length;
for(l=0;l<looplen;l++){
    div.removeChild(div.childNodes[l]);
}
```

**Documentation**

- Node.removeChild on MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.removeChild
- Node.childNodes on MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/childNodes

Comment: This might fire an exception, once an element is removed, the length changes; and the childNodes shift one position up.